# Cakephp3 Form button submit didn't work in the wizard

Tags: html, forms, cakephp-3.0

I had a forms of registraition  with html5 when i clicked the button submit nothing work  .

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/FOCompetence/users/inscription">
                <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"></div>
```

i used a wizard in the form

```html
<div class="panel-footer">
            <ul class="pager">
                <li class="previous disabled">
                    <a><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Précédant</a>
                </li>
                <li class="finish hidden pull-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-borders btn-primary"> Enregister</button>
                </li>
                <li class="next">
                    <a>Suivant <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div></form>
```

I tried many propositionts in the action like action="" ,action="#",action="inscription.ctp" and action="inscription" and nothing work 
my code of inscription methos in UsersController is :`public function inscription()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Welcome ^_^.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }`

Comment: the problem that i hadn't an error i, i replaced the tag<form> with <?= $this->Form->create($user) ?> and in the end i added  <li class="finish hidden pull-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-borders btn-primary"> Enregister</button>
                </li>
                <li class="next">
                    <a>Suivant <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            **<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>**  worked  withe the second button but i want the first button

Comment: please mention the problem to the question!